# Having troubles in making a GET request then a POST request to a different website using threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create a script that uses 20 threads in a while loop with a GET request on a website then POST to a different website.

I've tried with the threads module but I have no idea how to make it run.

Can someone help so I could understand how multithreading works on python? Below is the code.

```
import urllib2,requests
c = 0
while c<100:
    c=c+1
    first = urllib2.urlopen("http://numbersapi.com/"+str(c)+"/math").read()
    second = {'Tip':first}
    r = requests.post(url = "http://wwww.mywebsite.com/api.php", data=second).content
    print first
```

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Sorry first time using this website, I edited the post to make it more clear

Comment: Can you use `twisted` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using Python 2. I would recommend you install the `futures` package form `PYPI`. Then this would be one way (by the way, you don't seem to be doing anything with the result of the second request).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import urllib2, requests

def get_it(c):
    first = urllib2.urlopen("http://numbersapi.com/"+str(c)+"/math").read()
    second = {'Tip':first}
    r = requests.post(url = "http://wwww.mywebsite.com/api.php", data=second).content
    print first

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    for i in range(100):
        executor.submit(get_it, i)
```

Instead or printing the results, you may find it more convenient to return the results. The `submit` method returns `Future` object that can be tested for completion and the return value can be extracted from it:

```
from concurrent import futures
import urllib2, requests

def get_it(c):
    first = urllib2.urlopen("http://numbersapi.com/"+str(c)+"/math").read()
    second = {'Tip':first}
    r = requests.post(url = "http://wwww.mywebsite.com/api.php", data=second).content
    return first

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    the_futures = [executor.submit(get_it, i) for i in range(100)]
    for future in futures.as_completed(the_futures):
        print future.result()
```

If you want the results in the order in which you submit the requests, then:

```
from concurrent import futures
import urllib2, requests

def get_it(c):
    first = urllib2.urlopen("http://numbersapi.com/"+str(c)+"/math").read()
    second = {'Tip':first}
    r = requests.post(url = "http://wwww.mywebsite.com/api.php", data=second).content
    return first

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(get_it, range(100)):
        print result
```